# Pass two values from dropdowns to service in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to pass two values from two different dropdowns to my service. And I would like to do it on click on the button. So I wrote component like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryType } from '../models/category-type.enum';
import { CountryType } from '../models/country-type.enum';
import { NewsServiceService } from '../services/news-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  template:
    `
  <div>

    <select [(ngModel)]="catSelected" (ngModelChange) = "onClick($event)" >
        <option *ngFor = "let type of CategoryType.values()" [ngValue] = 'type'>
            {{type}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select [(ngModel)]="couSelected" (ngModelChange) = "onClick($event)" >
        <option *ngFor = "let type of CountryType.values()" [ngValue] = 'type'>
            {{type}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="onClick()">Click to get news</button>
    </div>
`
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  CategoryType = CategoryType;
  CountryType = CountryType;
  title: string;
  couSelected: string;
  catSelected: string;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsServiceService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.catSelected = 'Select_Category';
    this.couSelected = 'Select_Country';
  }
  onClick(catSelected: string, couSelected: string) {
    this.newsService.getNews(catSelected, couSelected).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.catSelected = data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Like i wrote I have two dropdowns with values 
`CategoryType`
`CountryType`

and one button to submit the click.

Every change on dropdown makes ngModelChange and send only one value to my services.
I wanna achive:

1. Select  value from `CategoryType`
2. Select value from `CountryType`
3. Then Click the button and pass values CategoryType and CountryType to my service.

Right now only one value is passed and I dont know why.

`onClick` function does not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two **main** problems with your code:

1. You're getting `catSelected` and `couSelected` from parameters, but you could use simply `this` reference:

```
onClick() {
  this.newsService.getNews(this.catSelected, this.couSelected)...
}
```

3. You're using `ng-click` instead of `(click)`, that's why button's click isn't being fired. Do this:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Click to get news</button>
```

---

That being said, I want to give you some tips:

1. Don't call *functions* in templates. Instead, declare `CategoryType` and `CountryType` like this:

```
readonly categoryTypes = CategoryType.values();
readonly countryTypes = CountryType.values();
```

2. Don't use `[ngValue]` for primitive types. It isn't necessary. You can just use `[value]`.

Answer (score 2):

Becouse your are passing only one value to onClick() function.

Correct by passing the elements from inside of `DropdownComponent` instead of passing it as `click($event)`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryType } from '../models/category-type.enum';
import { CountryType } from '../models/country-type.enum';
import { NewsServiceService } from '../services/news-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  template:
    `
  <div>

    <select [(ngModel)]="catSelected" >
        <option *ngFor = "let type of CategoryType.values()" [ngValue] = 'type'>
            {{type}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select [(ngModel)]="couSelected">
        <option *ngFor = "let type of CountryType.values()" [ngValue] = 'type'>
            {{type}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="onClick()">Click to get news</button>
    </div>
`
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  CategoryType = CategoryType;
  CountryType = CountryType;
  title: string;
  couSelected: string;
  catSelected: string;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsServiceService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.catSelected = 'Select_Category';
    this.couSelected = 'Select_Country';
  }
  onClick() {
    this.newsService.getNews(this.catSelected, this.couSelected).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.catSelected = data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I run your code and still it does not work. I put console.log in onClick() to check if its starting. And onClick() is not starting at all. 
So any other ideas? Or am I doing something wrong with this code?

Comment: this is stackblitz example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nerua9